# Process state kept in PCB and thread state kept in TCB

Tags: operating-system

Assume process p0 has been created. P0 has two threads (main thread) t0 and t1. So somewhere there is PCB0 for p0, TCB0 for t0 and TCB1 for t1.
(5 execution states for simplicity: created, ready, running, blocked, terminated)

1. The p0 is in running state when at least one of it's threads is in running state?
2. For sure in TCB there must be a field for thread state. If the p0 state can be directly calculated from the state of it's threads: Is there a field of execution state in PCB and why?
3. If the answer in 2 is yes: Each time a thread state is changing do we have to check the state of all process' threads in order to keep the PCB.state up to date? This isn't redundant?

Comment: Why would a process need an execution state when it is not a unit of execution?

Comment: I could have asked your question. It's sort and far more comprehensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The p0 is in running state when at least one of it's threads is in
> running state?

Not everytime. Process state and thread state can be different. So it is not necessary when thread is in running `p0` remains in running it can be  in block or ready state. Some of the possible situation between thread and process :

The process is in ready state, one of the process’s threads is in running state.

The process is blocked in blocked state, one of the process’s threads is in running state.

e.g. when threaded application starts as a process containing single thread . At that time process  is in running state. Then application uses user level thread library to create additional threads. Now when thread A begins to run it will enter the running state.Suppose Thread A make an I/O system call . In this situation control is transferred to the kernel which blocks the process .In this case thread A is still in running , even though the process is in blocked state. This is one of the example when process is blocked but thread is running.

> For sure in TCB there must be a field for thread state.

yes there is field for state(e.g running , terminate , ready , block etc ) in tcb.

> Is there a field of execution state in PCB and why?

Yes there is field of state in PCB too. But it is not calculated from tcb state because as I told both state can be different. Thread will generally call different procedures and thus a different execution history.

Hope you satisfy with my answer . Good luck :-)

---> [Check this link for reference](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/300/jregan/lectures/lecture6.ppt)

---> [check link for content of TCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_control_block) and [PCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_control_block)

Comment: May I have comment please for down vote so I can improve the answer ?

Comment: I am updating the answer  please read reference  if you think this answer is wrong.

Comment: I have only answered first question not each one I hope you rethink about your down vote decision

Comment: Thank you for consider down vote on this answer .I am really thankful to you.:-)